# Wordpress Custom Capability not assigned

Tags: wordpress, roles

I created a custom role and a custom capability. The custom capability is also to be added to the administrator role. However, neither of these roles receive that capability.

In the activation function:

```
add_role( 'x_manager', 'X Manager', array(
    'read' => true
) );
$role = get_role( 'x_manager' );
$role->add_cap( 'manage_x' );
$role = get_role( 'administrator' );
$role->add_cap( 'manage_x' );
```

I then check with

```
 $role_object = get_role( 'x_manager' );
   if( !$role_object->has_cap( 'manage_x' )){
               print('nope');
           }
   if( $role_object->has_cap( 'manage_x' )){
                       print('yup');
                   }
```

for both roles I get a 'nope' when checking for 'manage_x', but a yup for 'read'.

Any suggestions?